# Return value from modal Angular-UI bootstrap even if an error has occurred

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have read a lot of questions about how catch error in modal Bootstrap but none of them explain return value from modal in that case.

This code invokes modal:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'dummy/test',
        controller: 'modalController',
        size: 'lg',
    }).result.then(function (result) {
        $scope.numAttachs = result;
    }, function (error) {
        // return value???
    });
```

In *modalController* :

```
/*... Some logic ...*/

// Button returns values. 
$scope.saveValues = function () {
    $scope.$close($scope.numAttachs);  // This works fine
}
// Event triggered when modal controller destroy
$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    //$scope.$close($scope.numAttachs); // nope...
    // Here I would return value
});
```

My purpose is to return varible *numAttachs* in all cases:

- User presses *Save* button. (I get it)
- User presses in backdrop. (I do not get it)
- User presses in esc key. (I do not get it)

I don't like implicate event '$destroy' in solution, it was a desperate measure. I suppose there is any way to catch error and to get a return value but I can not find it. 
When I catch error in  *function (error) { // return value ?}* variable *error* takes values "escape key press" or "backdrop click" and there is not way to return value. Any suggestion?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, without disabling the backdrop click or escape key press, there is no way to pass a configurable value back to the `reject` function handler - namely, the only acceptable solution is for you to call `dismiss()` yourself.  Those two messages `escape key press` and `backdrop click` are hard-coded.

I could see a use case in allowing the user to specify an optional value to return but that might be a hard sell for the rest of the team.  I'll ask.  In the interim, one think you could do, and yes, it stinks, is store your information on a service that's injected into the code where you're operating on the promise returned by the open modal action.  I know, I know....it stinks.

Comment: It's a pity... I put the question as accepted for giving me the certainty that it can not be done.

Answer (score 1):

Other posiblity is not allow to user press esc key or backdrop putting:

```
backdrop : 'static',   // to prevent popup close by backdrop click
keyboard :false        // to prevent popup close by esc key
```

The user only can go out with buttons where I can return values.